# A real world Scope Guard using C++11 for exception safe resource management

Tags: c++, c++11

I need a Scope Guard class for exception safe resource management that is simple and using C++11 features.

For legacy C style APIs, the 1st choice is to design a wrapper class to allocate/cleanup resources in ctor/dtor. If such effort is too much, then the scope guard shall be used as a simple legacy API wrapper. The scope guard statement shall immediately follow its resource allocation counter part (e.g. fopen()).

Comment: What is the actual *question*?

Comment: What is the reason for requiring C++11 features, rather than requiring just to have a scope guard?

Comment: [Here](https://ricab.github.io/scope_guard/) you go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There is proposal to include `scope_exit`and `unique_resource`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4189.pdf), and I think it has been accepted. You can easily [find implementations on github](https://gist.github.com/socantre/b45b3e23e6f1f4715f08).

The `unique_resource` is specifically defined for your use-case of resource management:

```
auto hFile = std::make_unique_resource_checked(
    CreateFile("test.tmp",
               FILE_ALL_ACCESS,
               FILE_SHARE_READ,
               OPEN_EXISTING,
               FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
               nullptr), // The resource
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, // Don’t call CloseHandle if it failed!
    CloseHandle); // Clean-up API, lambda-friendly position
```

Comment: +1 for nice link and for an actual answer! ScopeGuard can be useful, especially in code that deals with classes that don't follow the RAII pattern. Those people who still have to maintain and use older code or C++03 will value ScopeGuard.

Comment: Do the linked scope guard code handle exception throwing cleanup?  That is the hard part.

Comment: @yakk I wondered about it aswell and found the paper says that they changed to now catch and rethrow, but instead let the exception propagate. Not sure about the pro and cons

Comment: Currently newest version is http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0052r0.pdf, though there should be a revision in the post-Kona mailing.

Comment: Putting resource allocation and deallocation in a single statement is the final goal for Scope Guard.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: don't. Using ScopeGuard to manage resources is a massive anti-pattern. It's RAII but strictly inferior. It's a completely false economy.

A scope guard works when you use a given resource in at most one place, and even then, a `unique_ptr` with a function deleter can do that too, but not be utterly terrible.